# Python Matplotlib - turn off autoscale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib, and I want to compare the graphs of 2 datasets by keeping the x and y axis same for both datasets. However, autoscale keeps butting in and rescaling my graphs a bit, because dataset 2 has smaller limit. As seen in pictures.

```
def make_figure(data, param ='Customers'):  # default param is Customers
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (18,10))

    xticks = np.arange(0, 10000, 1000)
    yticks = np.arange(0, 55000, 5000)

    i = 0
    colors = ['red','yellow','brown','orange','green','green','green','green','blue','cyan','navy','magenta']

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,4,1)
    ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
    ax1.set_yticks(yticks)
    ax1.autoscale(False, tight=False)

    for assortment in ['a','b','c']:
        for storetype in ['a','b','c','d']:

            datax = data[param][data.StoreType == storetype][data.Assortment == assortment]
            datay = data['Sales'][data.StoreType == storetype][data.Assortment == assortment]
            plt.subplot(3, 4, i+1, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
            plt.title('Assortment ' + assortment + ' StoreType ' + storetype)
            plt.scatter(y = datay, x = datax, c=colors[i], alpha=.65)

            if i % 4 == 0:
                plt.ylabel('Sales')

            if i >= 8:
                plt.xlabel(str(param))

            i += 1

    plt.tight_layout()

    return plt.show()
```

Dataset 1

[image]

Dataset 2

[image]

Comment: @tacaswell: I know the 2 questions sound similar, but I tried set_xlim() and it didn't produce the result I want.

Comment: ok.  question re-opened.

Comment: actually now I fixed it. I need to put ax = plt.subplot() and ax.set_xlim() and ax.set_ylim() **inside** the loop.

Comment: well, now I can't re-close it!  I suggest answering your own question.  You might also do better wit `fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(4, 4, sharex='all', sharey='all')` and looping over the axes object in `ax_array` (which is a 4x4 numpy array).

Answer (score 0):

You can user the xlim and ylim functions to set the limits of each axis.
If the limits are constant, for example:

```
# Set the limits and disable scaling
plt.xlim(0, 8000)
plt.ylim(0, 40000)
plt.autoscale(False)
```

A more general solution would be to determine your max limit based on all datasets you plan to plot beforehand, and set the limits likewise.

Comment: I tried it actually. I added ax1.set_xlim([0,8000])
    ax1.set_ylim([0,45000])

Comment: but result is the same

Comment: actually now I fixed it. I need to put ax = plt.subplot() and ax.set_xlim() and ax.set_ylim() inside the loop.

Comment: Aha, I see. I was just now trying to understand whether this was inside for loop. Also, sorry I did not mention set_xlim() and set_ylim() for subplots.